# qml Anchoring with something inside a Row

Tags: qt, qml

Imagine I want something like that :

```
  INPUT1  |    INPUT2    |   INPUT3
------------------------------------
  FIELD1  |    FIELD2    |   FIELD3
FIELDBIS1 |  FIELDBIS2   |  FIELDBIS3
```

I will do something close of :

```cpp
Column {
    Row {
        INPUT1{}
        INPUT2{}
        INPUT3{}
    }

    Separator{}

    Row {
        FIELD1{anchor.horizontalCenter : input1.horizontalCenter;}
        FIELD2{anchor.horizontalCenter : input2.horizontalCenter;}
        FIELD3{anchor.horizontalCenter : input3.horizontalCenter;}
    }

    Row {
        FIELDBIS1{anchor.horizontalCenter : input1.horizontalCenter;}
        FIELDBIS2{anchor.horizontalCenter : input2.horizontalCenter;}
        FIELDBIS3{anchor.horizontalCenter : input3.horizontalCenter;}
    }
}
```

But since field, fieldbis and input are not at the same size, how can I do?
Is there a better way than anchoring to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `spacing` for equally sized looking columns.

```
Column {
    spacing: 10    
     Row {
          spacing: 10
           ----
           ----
     }    
}
```

Comment: Okay for the vertical way, mais how to get aligned horizontally objects?